# AWS API Gateway: Error 429 Too many requests

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, put, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a **backend** system with **AWS API Gateway** and **Lambda**.
In the past days I created a PUT method for a new API resource, with an API Key as a simple first security step. The PUT method invoke a Lambda function on AWS.
Then I deployed this API to a "prod" stage for some tests.

**In the first days everything were working well as expected**: I created a call to the API with postman and I received all the data I was expecting.
But a couple of days ago I started to receive **always** the **429** *"Too many requests"* response. I created also a new stage, but nothing changed: also the new stage, with the same version or with newer version, is getting always the same error.
The API is not reaching any limit, because they are called 4 or 5 times per **day**, not per second (checked on CloudWatch). There is no cycle, it is only a single invocation. 
I suppose there is no error on the lambda side, because if I test the API in the AWS API Gateway console I get no error (and the lambda was working well in the past, no new changes from that version). The error only shows when I use an external client to test my api (in my case it is Postman).

Can anyone help to solve this problem?

UPDATE: I've just created a POST method on the same resource, with the same parameters and the same lambda. It is working. I wonder if the problem is related to the **PUT** methods in general or if within 2 days also my **POST** method will be affected by the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. I deleted and recreated the deployment. It did work in my case.

Comment: While automating first time, this happened for me only once. Once I deleting resources of the API manually, automation recreated and issue did not occur again.

Comment: I found increasing the plan limit resolved the issue for me. It was at 10000 for the month. I had a recursive query that triggered during testing and used up the plan quota for the month. Raising the quota to 15000 req / month allowed me to continue testing.

Comment: I deleted the entire Cloud-Formation stack and recreated it for it to work.

Comment: My problem was that I added a default_route_settings block in my Terraform configuration for an existing API Gateway stage to enable detailed logging. That set the "default route throttling" values to 0 even though I didn't have them in my config. (They might have been manually set in the past, not sure.) Setting them to non-zero values fixed the 429 issue.

Comment: we just hit the same issues as acj above. If you're using the AWS terraform api gateway module and decide to set the logging_level to something to err...debug....the terraform plan will also add in throttling limits set to 0. Note 0 isn't 'throttling disabled' it's a 0 limit so you then discover the api is blocking all requests (seemingly as a result of you just enabling debugging). 
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-apigateway-v2/blob/master/main.tf

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/handling-errors/) is a link to errors related to Amazon's API gateway. The last paragraph has additional information on the 429 error you discussed above.

Comment: Already seen, but is not helping. About the additional information, if you are talking about "Error Retries and Exponential Backoff", I'm trying manually with seconds or minutes and also days between one requests and another. Nothing changes.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I created the case in AWS, and they suggested that I implement this dependsOn fix in the template file. Refer: [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html)

And it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).